# Verifique se uma string está nula ou vazia no XSLT

Tags: xml, soap, xslt

Tenho esse trecho de código XML e preciso verificar se esta vazio:

```
<CNPJ>
    <xsl:if "cnpjContratado"!=NULL>
        <xsl:value-of select="cnpjContratado"/>
    </xsl:if>
</CNPJ>
<CPF>
    <xsl:if "cpfContratado"!=NULL>
        <xsl:value-of select="cpfContratado"/>
    </xsl:if>
</CPF>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolução do problema:

```
<CNPJ>
    <xsl:if test="cnpjContratado != NULL">
        <xsl:value-of select="cnpjContratado"/>
    </xsl:if>
</CNPJ>
<CPF>
    <xsl:if test="cpfContratado != NULL">
        <xsl:value-of select="cpfContratado"/>
    </xsl:if>
</CPF>
```